# consuming web api method manually in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is the most dumb question you might come across regarding Web Api but being a newbie i am struggling to find an answer to this simple question.
In the codebelow if i can easily call the one that returns "number" but the other one with the Add method i just cant find the right way to call it as everytime i try i get the 404 error

Could anyone please tell me how can i call that method "Add" with appropriate parameter?

```
namespace WebAPIServices.Controllers
{
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public string Get()
    {
        return "number";
    }

    //how can i call this one?
    public int Add(int num1,int num2)
    {
    return num1+num2;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call it at `http"//<hostname>/api/values/add?num1=1&num2=2`

And you need to add the `[HttpGet]` attribute because otherwise it defaults to `[HttpPost]`... You may need to add a route as well.

```
//how can i call this one?
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/values/add")]
public int Add(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anthony i tried that but its calling the method that returns "number" as message

Comment: Yep sorry, you need to set up the route for it. If you're using Web API 2 you can add `[HttpGet]` and `[Route("api/values/add")]` on the method.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony. That nailed it.

Comment: @Sike12 You actually don't need to add a route. Just need to tell it that it's a GET.

Comment: Ok Anthony i found out the route has to be added otherwise the call will fail :)

Comment: Interesting. I had tried it out and managed to get it working without the route. I'll take a look again later to see what happened. Updated the answer with the route attribute.

Comment: Hi Anthony! Yes i think thats how WebAPI2 works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Web API 2 , you can use Attribute Routing ([Web Api 2 Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

as follows:

and then invoke it from the browser or a console app :

http:///api/values/add?num1=11&num2=12

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Kaz-LA. I am using webapi (the first version) for now